# How should I define the following module in order to make it working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to extend with a class (module) (1) a Backbone.Collection var `MessageCollection.prototype` (2).

How should I define the following module in order to make it working?

---

(1)

```
/*global define, setTimeout*/
define([
    'underscore'
], function (_) {
    "use strict";

    return {
        startPolling: function () {
            this.polling = true;
            this.executePolling();
//            _.bindAll(this, 'onFetch', 'startPolling', 'stopPolling');
        },

        stopPolling: function () {
            this.polling = false;
        },

        executePolling: function () {
            this.fetch({success : this.onFetch});
        },

        onFetch: function () {
            var self = this;
            console.log(this); // undefined
            console.log(self); // undefined
            if (this.polling) { // Cannot read property 'polling' of undefined 
                setTimeout(this.executePolling, 1000 * 60 * this.minutes);
            }
        }

    }

    return Poll;

});
```

---

(2)

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'moment',
    '../utils/poller'
], function (_, Backbone, Poller) {
    'use strict';

    var MessageCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        // some code
    });

    _.extend(MessageCollection.prototype, Poller);

    return MessageCollection;
});
```

---

```
var messageCollection = new MessageCollection();
messageCollection. startPolling(); // Cannot read property 'polling' 
                          // of undefined (see the comment on the code)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be with your `setTimeout`.  When a function is passed to `setTimeout`, it's executed in the global scope.

So, `this.executePolling` is called in the global scope, meaning that `this` inside that function will be `window`.

Try changing it to:

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function(){
    that.executePolling
}, 1000 * 60 * this.minutes);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but it is not right, I added more details to my question. hopefully it will be help. Anyway `Cannot read property 'polling' of undefined` it means this is not window.

Comment: @LorraineBernard: It was just a thought, oh well =/